# how to write a kernel module to display the code running in current kernel

Tags: debugging, ubuntu, linux-kernel

how to real time display the current code running in kernel with kernel module in ubuntu and moreover to use keyboard key to control stop and continue running ubuntu kernel

when compile a custom linux kernel, it takes so long to run. for just a small changes takes a long time to see the result, is there a fast way?

```
#include <linux/module.h>    // included for all kernel modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>      // included for __init and __exit macros

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Lakshmanan");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A Simple Hello World module");

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world!\n");
    return 0;    // Non-zero return means that the module couldn't be loaded.
}

static void __exit hello_cleanup(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning up module.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_cleanup);
```

Comment: Nohow. You need t32, there is no way to do this in kernel module ...

Comment: how to get list form dictionary?

Comment: Question editing is meant for clarification or providing additional information about the problem at hand. Please don't edit questions to become completely different questions. Post a new question [as a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.